# Room crushes on release

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room in my project, all went well, but then when I try to run it on release it crushes giving me this error

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for via.rider.repository.ai. ai_Impl does not exist`

I saw that all the questions were about problems with `build.config` but I do have `annotationProcessor` configured

```
// Android Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$roomVersion"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
```

What could it be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Selvin what is missing?

Comment: well, I tried minimal example(from google) with information provided by you in the question an it is working for me in release mode

Comment: @Selvin good for you

Comment: free hint: proguard is, what in most cases, cause problems with release version

Comment: @Selvin that's what I thought, but searching Google for a pro guard for Room didn't provide anything. If you happen to have a working progaurd would you like to share it?

Comment: Try adding -keep class via.rider.repository.** { *; } to your proguard-rule.pro. I'm pretty sure that Room is trying to generate db schema and instead of your classes it just gets some obfuscated pulp

Comment: @muminers thanks! happy to find good helping people, that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Room is trying to generate db schema and instead of your classes it just gets some obfuscated pulp. Try adding:

```
-keep class via.rider.repository.** { *; }
```

to your proguard-rule.pro